# Number of Sundays in a list of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a list of members of a club together with dates that they attended the club. I need to know how many Sundays did each member attend over a given period. I have a table that lists each attendance, made up of member number and the attendance date.

Eg In this example 13/1 and 20/1 are Sundays

```
MEMBER                 ATTENDANCE

12345                  13/1/13

12345                  14/1/13

56789                  13/1/13

56789                  14/1/13

56789                  20/1/13

24680                  14/1/13

24680                  15/1/13
```

Ideally I would like to see this returned:

```
MEMBER                 # OF SUNDAYS

12345                  1

56789                  2

24680                  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select MEMBER, 
sum(case when datename(weekday,ATTENDANCE)='Sunday' then 1 else 0 end) as no_of_sundays 
from table 
group by MEMBER
```

EDIT : To handle duplicate dates, use

```
select MEMBER, 
sum(case when datename(weekday,ATTENDANCE)='Sunday' then 1 else 0 end) as no_of_sundays 
from (select distinct MEMBER,ATTENDANCE from table ) as t 
group by MEMBER
```

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that as the date field is actaully a datetime field with the possibility of multiple entries for the same member on the same day. In this situation the count is accounting for both entries. How can I restrict each 'Sunday' to returned only once?